# How to create a responsive top bar with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a top bar that has two sections. The first one is the 230px section (i.e., the black one). The second section is the ash one. I want the second section as another div.

[image]

My problem arises when I open it on a big screen. The following is happening:

[image]

Here is the HTML Code below:

```
<div id="topNav">
<div class="websiteName">
    <h1><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Admin Panel</h1>
</div>
<div class="topbar">
    <a class="mainMenuTrigger" data-type="on"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i></a>
    <a class="settingsTrigger"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-fw"></i></a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#topNav{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.websiteName{
    width: 230px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #242A34;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.websiteName h1{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
}
.topbar{
   background: #fff;
   display: block;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   width: 1135px;
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: try position:relative; for #topNav class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

- `width: calc(100% - 230px);`: This allows for the responsive top bar.
- Stripped off the `float` and instead of `inline-block`, use `position: absolute`

See below for a somewhat bare bones example:

```css
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#topNav {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.websiteName {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 230px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #242A34;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.websiteName h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.topbar {
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 230px;
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 230px);
}
```

```html
<div id="topNav">
  <div class="websiteName">
    <h1>Admin Panel</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="topbar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It calculates for you a width that you can't write out simply as `width: 100% - 230px;`. See: https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this below css will solve issue
here you need to divide both div as per there width div so you need to use **width: calc(100% - 230px);**

```
.topbar{
   background: #000;
   display: block;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   width: calc(100% - 230px);
   float: left;
}
```